# Facebook says my Facebook page is not valid and it is

Tags: facebook

I keep getting this message when I try to add the Like Box to my blog:

The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook page, but "http://www.facebook.com/OneBrownGirl" is not a valid Facebook page.

Since I know my page is valid, what do I do?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Facebook Page. This is your Facebook Profile.
You can create a Facebook page here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/create/

Answer (score 1):

From the Facebook Like Box social plugin page: "The Like Box is a social plugin that enables Facebook Page owners to attract and gain Likes from their own website."

Like Box is for Facebook Pages. If you enter a URL value on the Like Box social plugin preview page and the URL does not render a Like Box then a WordPress plugin implementing the Like Box social plugin would be no different.

Facebook has separate profile badges which may be supported by other WordPress plugins.http://www.linkyiwu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the facebook page you created, then click on setting and on the very bottom of the page you will see facebook page ID. pick the whatever iD for the page and paste where the

Comment: Could you make this answer complete, as it seems to be a bit "cut off".